# I am looking for the answer of problems set of the book 'Principles of computer system desgin: an introduction'

Tags: resources

Ican't find the answer of problems set. and I am denied by the server, which may own the answer.
This is the server,https://akugue.com/docs/les-of-computer-system-design-solution-manual-pdf-4753998

I need the answer of problems set to help me understanding the concepts mentioned in this book. I can't make it sense without practice. Thank you!

Comment: are they written at the end of the book?

Comment: No,the problems set without answer is written at end of the book.